# eclipse ADT Bluetooth receive crash

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I got this bluetooth code from another blog. I was able to setup connection and send data through bluetooth. I cannot receive. I have been working with this same code for a while and just stumped.  I am a new be and could use some help. The app is a simple send 2 bytes and receive 2 bytes.

```
   void beginListenForData()
        {
            final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character
            rcdata.setText("DataRC");           //NEW
            stopWorker = false;
            readBufferPosition = 0;
            readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()

            {
                public void run()
                {    
                rcdata.setText("DataRC0");          // Test NEW
                   while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                   {
                        try 
                        {
                            int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();  

                            if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                                rcdata.setText("DataRC1");          // Test NEW
                                for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                                {

                                    byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                    if(b == delimiter)
                                    {
                                        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                        final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                        readBufferPosition = 0;

                                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                rcdata.setText(data);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (IOException ex) 
                        {
                            stopWorker = true;
                        }
                   }
                }
            });

            workerThread.start();
        }
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace if it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you listen on non ui thread
and i suppose rcdata is edit or text view 
you should use this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

for all rcdata.setText calls

Comment: rcdata.setText("DataRC1"); is just a marker for testing. I did not intend it to display receive data just to conform a routine

Comment: U can use Log.d for that

Comment: I am a new be,  I will have to learn log.d I use a Android device Samsung tablet III  not the emulator. I am coming from MSBasic so its a rather large leaning curve.

Comment: Try Log.d("myapp", data);

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: yes it will work for both. mostly everything work on both this is why emulators are done. After all this talking you could've just try it and also give the stacktrace of the errors you get as dymmeh says, to tell you where exactly the errors are, as i based my answer on predictions.

Comment: Again A new be,  I did try before asking but it did not work. Your answers are very difficult to understand. Our definition of emulators may not be the same. I appreciate your feedback but I think I will wait for additional comments from others.

Comment: djodjo, sorry for my comment I am frustrated! I got the log working with your help. Sending data is fine but Still no in coming   
data.      Log.d("myApp",  String.format("EAN-8: %d", bytesAvailable));